# how to maintain paragraph?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php-5.3

i have a problem
when i insert some articles which includes paragraph to database
at the time of retrieval it display article but without paragraph.
so it look like dirty writing on the page.
so is there any trick or code for save article with paragraph & at time of display it shows as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML ignores carriage returns and collapses multiple spaces. You have to insert the appropriate tags, such as `<br>`. Have a look at [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br).

Comment: ya but at the output it shows <br> tag
so in output article display with <br>,which look like error on page

Comment: hey dude i am extremely sorry
this code works thanks.
actually i just show example on that website & commented you that it show <br>.But when i run the code then i sow it works fine without <br> tag.
sorry again
& thanks for your valuable help